# How can I move ReSharper License from one computer to another?

Tags: resharper

I have ReSharper installed with Visual Studio on a machine.

I want to now use Visual Studio on a different machine, with ReSharper.

Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. You need to have the "Personal License" in order to do this in compliance with the license terms. Simply install Resharper, and input your name and registration key.

According to: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/buy.jsp#personal_licenseTerms

> A Personal License is a named-user
>   license which restricts the use of the
>   software to the person who purchased
>   that license. The license allows for
>   installation of the software on
>   different computers (at work and/or at
>   home), provided that multiple
>   instances of the software will not be
>   used at the same time.

If you have purchased another license than the Personal one, I would suggest you contact Jetbrains and ask them if your license allows it. In particular, I think that whether you can do this with the Commercial License, would depend on the exact usage scenario.

I personally have a Personal license and use ReSharper on both my work pc, home pc, and on my laptop - with no problems. You can only use it on one of the installed computers at the same time.

Comment: Actually, you can use a personal license on more than one computer at the same time. For example, if you yourself work on two computers side-by-side, you only need one personal license. You can verify this by writing jetBrains and asking them about your specific scenario.

Comment: @shovavnik That's not a thing you can do. You can use re#er on multiple machines, but not "side-by-side." If you want to run VS on both systems, you need two full re#er licenses.

Comment: @EKW I'm neither a lawyer nor a jetBrains employee, so I won't argue the point. However, I'm also not making it up. I actually wrote to jetBrains and asked whether I can use my single personal license on multiple machines on my network simultaneously. jetBrains obliged me. All I'm saying is that you should ask jetBrains directly if you're not sure.

Comment: @shovavnik I have two copies here. In order to use a license on one machine, I have to close Visual Studio on the other machine. It isn't a question of asking a human. The re#er dialog that tells me I can't use it because it is currently in use on another system is clear.

Comment: @EKW I understand. That's exactly the problem I was having. jetBrains told me how to work around that problem. Consider that as long as it really is one person using both machines, there's little difference between that situation and having two Visual Studios open on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Personal license** as quoted by Jetbrains.

> With the new subscription model started November 2015, you can run multiple personal licensed copies at the same time (like on laptop and desktop for remote debugging client/server apps).

**For Commercial license** your operating system username (login) must be the same on all the systems where you will run multiple tool copies at the same time.

> The same is true for the commercial subscriptions, however, there is also an additional requirement: your operating system username (login) must be the same on all the systems where you will run multiple tool copies at the same time.

If a single License Key is used on two machines at the same time and the requirement is not being followed, the following information dialog will appear:

*Another instance of ReSharper with the same License is running...*

[image: 'Another instance of ReSharper with the same License' error message]

[Original thread](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242835--Another-instance-of-ReSharper-with-the-same-License-error-message)